# java crawler: a ClientProtocolException error when httpClient initiated the request

Tags: java, web-crawler, httpclient

I wanna fetch the page data after simulating login the website. And the exception occurs.

## problem:

`java
org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at spider.SimulatePALogin.afterLoginPager(SimulatePALogin.java:92)
    at spider.SimulatePALogin.main(SimulatePALogin.java:41)
Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Content-Length header already present
    at org.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent.process(RequestContent.java:96)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:132)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:182)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    ... 4 more`

```java

```
    HttpUriRequest httpUriRequest = new HttpPost(
            "https://icore-pts.pingan.com.cn/ebusiness/login");
        // ?Accept?: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
    httpUriRequest.setHeader("Host","pacas-login.pingan.com.cn");
    ......// set headers here 
    httpUriRequest.setHeader("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests","1");
    httpUriRequest
            .setHeader(
                    "User-Agent",
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.89 Safari/537.36");

    // the ClientProtocolException occurs here
    HttpResponse response = HttpUtils.httpClient.execute(httpUriRequest);
```

```

How can I fix it?

thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's my bad not to review the error msg.

I set the "content length" header which makes the exception occurs.